# need help on android studio google map

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

above is the error message while i run the simulation on genymotion 
i updated all the api, actived the google+ for genymotion

i create a google map project from the default project from android studio. can anyone help me out from here?

try suggestion from google 
like downgrade the dependencies, add in the multidex true and etc but it still show this error.... yes, i have added the api key also

---

thanks everyone but i still having error after adding all the suggestions
please see the image below
[image]

Comment: Please show your gradle file

Comment: Definitely a mutlidex issue, enable mutlidex as follows

Comment: anyone know why my "MultiDex.install(getTargetContext())" is showing Red?

Comment: replace it with getApplicationContext() or this, whichever works for you !

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have gone past the ~65000 method limit. Try enabling multidex if you 're using recent versions of the Android build tools

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.android.support', name : 'multidex', version: '1.0.1'
}
```

In your android config

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        // flag
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

There should be an entry in manifest or in application class(if it's there) too

```
<application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
```

or if you have an application class then do this instead of above manifest entry

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    ...
}
```

Edit:

You must be using build tools > 21.1.*

Comment: either the docs of multidex has been updated or if not the i guess there should be an entry in manifest too or in application class if it's there , verify it ,+1

Comment: @PavneetSingh this is the part where inheritance screws you. If you were extending a custom `Application` class that means you 're going to have to make a lot of changes. Thanks for edit

Comment: yeah could be though there's a lot depends upon application class when it comes to add other features , although inheritance not really screwed me yet :P :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Definitely a mutlidex issue, enable mutlidex as follows, 
 1. Add code
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

There should be an entry in manifest too

```
<application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
```

or if you have an application class then do this instead of above manifest entry

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    ...
}
```

2. And make sure you have clicked on sync at top right on build.gradle file, when it appears.
3. Clean and build.

   Theory:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
       If issue still persist give gradle file and error log.

Comment: please provide full solution next time if you gonna post it as answer +1